# How do I override the window.open function for all the iframes that are loaded by the current tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

There are a lot of scripts loaded a web page. I want to know what iframe is causing a new pop-up tab to open. I know I can override the window.open for current iframe by going in the Chrome's developer tools option and writing `window.open = function () { debugger; }` for the currently selected iframe. But there are a lot of iframes and by the time I write this line for all the iframes manually, the page reloads.

Is there any way I could do that programatically?

Comment: Are all the iframes using the same domain as the main page? If they are not then you cannot

Comment: Even if the extension that loaded them is the same?

Comment: Yes it doesnt matter what creates them, be it javsacript, some extension, etc if they do not use the same domain trying to access the iframe will cause a cross origin error

Comment: Ok, thanks! Could you please tell me the way, assuming they belong to the same domain?